Conditionally generate HTML based on the value of database using JavaScript
I'm new to JavaScript and I'm at a loss to why this isn't working.
I have a .csv files that fills a chart using its data, I want to apply a certain CSS class/id when one of the value in the database is true.
Here is my HTML:
<div class="box-hidden" ${d.data.mobile_masque === true ? 'id="blur-effect"' : ''}> ${d.data.mobile.replace(/(.{2})/g, "$1 ")} </div>

So if d.data.mobile_masque is true, I want the HTML to be:
<div class="box-hidden" id="blur-effect"> ${d.data.mobile.replace(/(.{2})/g, "$1 ")} </div>

To render the chart I'm using this GitHub: https://github.com/bumbeishvili/org-chart
When I run the code in the page step by step I can see that the value of the d.data.mobile_masque is indeed true (see screenshot), but it doesn't add the id part.
If I try a ${console.log(d.data.mobile_masque)}; it just shows undefined; in the webpage.
Every other data have no issue on the page, it's just the comparator that doesn't seem to work or that I fail to use it correctly.

You're quite possibly getting the use of template literates wrong; would need to see more code as this doesn't look correct. As well usage of === is strict by value type whereas == may consider other types. 0 === false would equal false and 0 == false would equal true. Few things worth noting.

I don't see a screenshot. Instead of logging the full value what is printed if you just ${console.log(d.data) ? Please add the screenshot back if it got lost. There's currently not enough information here to help efficiently.

@BGPHiJACK thank you so much, this was the issue, it now works perfectly.
I changed it to
<div class="box-hidden" ${d.data.mobile_masque == 1 ? 'id="blur-effect"' : ''}> ${d.data.mobile.replace(/(.{2})/g, "$1 ")} </div>

@rand'Chris, thank you for taking the time to reply to my question, the screenshot was showing the browser console with a break point on the line and my mouse over d.data.mobile_masque showing it had the correct data.
d.data did have every data showing from my csv in the console using a breakpoint.
